# Mandate derived function implementation without making it pure

Tags: c++, virtual, maya

I have a feeling the answer will be it's not possible, at least I couldn't find anything in these regards, but I'm hoping to be surprised:

I'm inheriting and extending a class provided by an API, extension which in turns gets inherited a lot from various derived classes which would previously inherit the above base.
IE:
API provides `theirBase`.
Users normally would implement `class myCommand: public theirBase{};`
I've put together `class extendedBase: public theirBase{};` to be inherited instead.

That because of recurring patterns (pure boiler plate) I want to remove, and some recurring steps that require specific implementaiton that I want to make explicitly mandatory.
If you're familiar with Autodesk Maya it's MPxCommand I've extended.

Normally making them pure virtuals would do it, that's exactly the functionality I'm after, but there's a catch, the API requires commands to get registered implement a callback style static:

```
static void *creator() {return new myClass;}
```

so obviously no pure virtuals.

---

A basic derived and functional command (or one derived from my own specialized super of MPxCommand) would look something like this:

```
class myCommand: public MPxCommand{
public:
            myCommand(){};
    virtual ~myCommand(){};

    static void *creator(){ return new myCommand;} // <-- prevents pure virtual

    static MSyntax syntax // M* are provided API objects/types

    virtual MStatus doIt(const MArgList&);
    virtual MStatus redoIt();
    virtual MStatus undoIt();
protected:
    boilerPlate();
    virtual preflightCheck(){} // <- this I'd love to make pure, currently just warns
                               // currently it just warns about missing implementation
                               // as it should never be visible from a derived class
                               // and this class is purely a base

};
```

---

Currently I have no issues inheriting and extending it with several methods and the such, but methods that I want to be expressely and mandatorily implemented in further subs (which vary per sub) can only be virtual and non pure (I provide dummy implementations with a warning if they get called, pointing at an unimplemented derivation), therefore not ensuring that a future user will know that he HAS TO implement them without looking at comments in the source or doco lost somewhere or catch my warning in the log, not to mention I have no compile time protection from my own stupidity.

Is there a way for me to make the implementation of additional methods obviously mandatory that isn't pure virtuals?
Or some way to re-concretize parts of the class so pure virtuals will be exceptionally accepted despite the need for new in the static creator?

GCC 4.1.2, so I'm also cut off from many C++11 niceties (overrides and such), but for the sake of my own education I'll gladly take answers that might be forward looking to the day I won't be locked in to a jurassic API and compiler.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not have a CommandBase class that inherits from MPxCommand, and includes your pure virtual preflightCheck() definition?  It's perfectly valid to define a "non-creatable" derivation of MPxCommand, and only have a creator function for the actual implementation classes.


Also, I don't believe that the creator function even needs to be a member of the class it creates - it just needs to be globally accessible when you call the registration function with the Maya API

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to be able to have containers of `myCommand`? If you don't, you may be able to get a behavior similar to the one that you're looking for by making `myCommand` into a template class, where the template parameter would supply the behavior that would normally go in the virtual function.

```
template <typename PreflightChecker>
class myCommand: public MPxCommand{
public:
    myCommand(){};
    virtual ~myCommand(){};

    static void *creator(){ return new myCommand;} // <-- prevents pure virtual

    static MSyntax syntax // M* are provided API objects/types

    virtual MStatus doIt(const MArgList&);
    virtual MStatus redoIt();
    virtual MStatus undoIt();
protected:
    boilerPlate();
    virtual preflightCheck()
    {
        PreflightChecker::check();
    }
};

class MyPreflightChecker
{
public:
    static void check()
    {
        ...
    }
};

vector<MPxCommand> v;
myCommand<MyPreflightChecker> command;
v.push_back(command);
```

Comment: It might both mess with the registrar (likely will), and become a bit too unfamiliar to somebody adopting the class, who'd likely expect it to behave and handle the way the original would bar the extensions and some simple, additional mandates. Might still be worth tinkering with though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Instead of using a derived class to eliminate the boilerplate, you might be able to do it by providing a macro. This wouldn't completely eliminate the boilerplate, since the users would still need to include the macro, but it could cut it down substantially.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
class A {


  virtual void method() = 0 {
    // now the derived classes HAS to implement it
    // and you still get an implementation

  }

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unless I'm missing something that's a pure virtual, which means you won't be able to allocate an instance with new, and that's sadly a requirement of the API.

Comment: @ThE_JacO You are rigth. Sorry. I thought you could still instantiate an instance of the class.